# Poisson or Binomial

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

> A company has 6 customers, each one having 0.25 probability of calling on a given day. What is the probability that at least two customers call daily?

I want to use the Poisson distribution to do this but is it correct? Should I use the binomial distribution?

Comment: This can be easily done using binomial.

Comment: Is it a homework? Please see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add `[self-study]` tag if appropriate.

Comment: This has the `[self-study]` tag & some initial thoughts. I see no need for this to be closed.

Comment: Does "at least two customers" mean at least two *distinct* customers?  There's nothing in your suppositions that precludes the possibility that customers might call multiple times per day and your reference to the Poisson distribution suggests you might be entertaining that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that $\ge2$ customers call would be a binomial.  The [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) is for a count out of a fixed, known total, where each event has the same probability of 'success'.  The [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) is for a count that is not bounded (i.e., $[0, \infty)$).  In this situation, at most you could have $6$ customers call, because that is the number of unique customers that exist.  The customers could call more than once per day, I suppose, so the total number of calls could be $>6$, but that is a different question.

To solve for this question, we would inspect the complement of the CDF for $\mathcal{Bin}(n=6,\ p=.25)$ at $x=2$.

[image]

Doing this in `R`, we could do:

```r
1-pbinom(1, size=6, prob=.25)
# [1] 0.4660645
```

That is, there is a $\approx 46.6\%$ chance that $\ge2$ customers will call on a given day.